# Unity Making a Board

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make a board, that have 12 site. i tried to detect one of them with Overlapsphere, but i'm looking for a method to check the 12 site at the same time. so i can know how many object are in each site. anyone can help ?  maybe its possible to create an array of overlapSphere ?

here is the code:`enter code here`

```
public int count;
     [SerializeField]Vector3 position  = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
     float radius = 2f;
      [SerializeField] public Text counter;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //detectedball();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        detectedball();
      
    }
    void detectedball()
    {
         Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(position, radius);
        foreach (var hitCollider in hitColliders)
        {
           // hitCollider.SendMessage("Detected");
        if(gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {
            count++;
        }
          
        
         Debug.Log(count);
          // counter.text = hitCollider.ToString();
        }
    }

   void OnDrawGizmos()
   {
       Gizmos.color = Color.red;

       Gizmos.DrawWireSphere( position , radius);
   }
}
```

Comment: Well if it is a board you could have colliders on each square/area. Or just keep record of where stuff is?

Comment: I tried that, but i can't use more than one OnColliderEnter or Exit in a script. but i really want to be able to have them 12 in one script. or should a make different script for each slot of the board ?

Comment: Each square would be an object in its own right so have its own script